# ReSharper intellisense points to wrong function

Tags: javascript, resharper

Once upon a time I fat fingered "Function" instead of "function" in a js file. Now my intellisense auto points to the ECMAScript's "Function" instead of a typical "function" declaration in javascript. How can I tell Resharper to ignore the "Function" result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearing the caches would probably work - `Resharper`->`Options`->`Environment`->`General` and click the `Clear Caches` button.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to remove a single entry, but it resolved the problem I was having.

Comment: This is being fixed in Resharper: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-400812