# Function instead of function in Resharper

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

I have EcmaScript.js in my scripts folder and every time I write 'fun' and expect Resharper to complete with 'function' it writes 'Function' instead since it's in the EcmaScript script. How can I remove the 'Function' entry from intellisense or make 'function' the top choice?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21283306/how-do-you-remove-a-specific-entry-from-intellisense-resharper - try clearing your caches or try Resharper 8.1.1 for a bug fix.

Comment: Unfortunately, this problem persists in ReSharper releases beyond 8.1.1. I am on 8.1.23.546, and I'm seeing this same behavior.